# A pythonic way to sum the values of a dict with a specified key list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list (or other iterable object) `['a','b','c','d']`. I have a `dict` `X`. I can sum them up in the naive way:

```
s = 0
for k in ['a','b','c','d']:
    s += X[k]
```

But is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: There is nothing UN-Pythonic about that.

Comment: @o11c Counter is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi it depends on how XY this problem is.

Comment: @o11c We're summing dictionary values, not counting occurrences.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi that's exactly what `collections.Counter` *does* - it's not like it's limited to incrementing by ones. If OP can change the code that *generates* the dictionaries to canonicalize keys *first* and then construct a `Counter` ...

Comment: You don't understand. Counter counts occurrences. I'd like to see you try using it to total the dictionary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
s = sum(X[k] for k in ['a','b','c','d'])
```

Comment: Does it generate a list in Python 3 or a smaller iterable?

Comment: `sum` generates an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by using the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression). You can even iterate over the characters of a string:

```
s = sum(X[k] for k in 'abcd')
```

Comment: Or extra precaution: `sum(d.get(i, 0) for i in 'abcd')`

Comment: Note that 'a,b,c,d'<> ['a','b','c','d']